# Caesar Cipher with capital letters

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

So currently my Caesar cipher program runs well whenever I use lowercase letters. I want it however to work when I input a word or phrase with uppercase. This is the code I have now. Hopefully y'all can help me finish this.

## user defined functions

def encrypt(message, distance):
    """Will take message and rotate it the distance, in order to create an encrypted message"""

```
encryption = ""
for ch in message:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue + distance
    if cipherValue > ord("z"):
        cipherValue = ord("a") + distance - (ord("z") - ordvalue + 1)
    encryption += chr(cipherValue)
return encryption
```

def decrypt(message, distance):
    """Will decrypt the above message"""

```
decryption = ""
for cc in message:
    ordvalue = ord(cc)
    decryptValue = ordvalue - distance
    if decryptValue < ord("a"):
        decryptValue = ord("z") - distance - (ord("a") - ordvalue - 1)
    decryption += chr(decryptValue)
return decryption
```

def binaryConversion(message):
    """Will convert the word into binary code"""

```
binary = ""
for cb in message:
    binaryString = " " #Binary number
    binaryNumber = ord(cb)
    while binaryNumber > 0:
        binaryRemainder = binaryNumber % 2
        binaryNumber = binaryNumber // 2
        binaryString = str(binaryRemainder) + binaryString
    binary += binaryString
return binary
```

## while loop

run = True

while run:

```
#input 

message = input("Enter word to be encrypted: ") #original message
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: ")) #distance letters will be moved

#variables

fancy = encrypt(message, distance)
boring = decrypt(fancy, distance)
numbers = binaryConversion(message)

#output
print("\n")
print("Your word was: ", format(message, ">20s"))
print("The distance you rotated was: ", format(distance), "\n")
print("The encryption is: ", format(fancy, ">16s"))
print("The decryption is: ", format(boring, ">16s"))
print("The binary code is: ", format(numbers)) #I know an error comes here but it will work in the end

repeat = input("Would you like to encrypt again? Y/N ")
print("\n")
if repeat == "N" or repeat == "n":
    run = False
else:
    run = True
```

## Finale

print("Thank you & as Julius Caesar once said, 'Veni, vidi, vici'")

Thank you

Comment: I guess I miss explained. I tried that but I need it to print from the decryption with a capital letter also

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you approach this problem in the mindset of a mapping rather than an offset.  You can build the mapping based on the offset but character processing will be easier if you use a dictionary or some other form of one to one mapping.

For example:

```
  offset = 5
  source = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  target = source[offset:]+source[:offset]
  source = source + source.upper()
  target = target + target.upper()
  encrypt = str.maketrans(source,target)
  decrypt = str.maketrans(target,source)

  e = "The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy Dogs".translate(encrypt)
  print(e)
  d = e.translate(decrypt)
  print(d)
```